# WPF Get Stackpanel children neighbors

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, nearest-neighbor, stackpanel

I have a stackpanel that I have dynamically added buttons to, based on a 2D array defined elsewhere.  So essentially it builds a grid of buttons, but added as children of the stackpanel.  What I need to be able to do, is specify a child button based on column and row number. Here's the Stackpanel.

```
<StackPanel Name="myArea"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

And here's some of the code in question.

```
Grid values = new Grid();
values.Width = 320;
values.Height = 240;
values.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
values.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

int x = valueBoard.GetLength(0);
int y = valueBoard.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
    values.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
}
for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
{
    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
    values.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
}
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Content = "";
    button.Click += ButtonClick;  
    button.MouseRightButtonUp += RightClick;
    Grid.SetColumn(button, i);
    Grid.SetRow(button, j);
    values.Children.Add(button);
}
myArea.Children.Add(values);
```

So now, on click of a button, I want to hide all adjacent buttons in the grid.  Here's my click event:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int col = Grid.GetColumn((Button)sender);
    int row = Grid.GetRow((Button)sender);
    Button source = e.Source as Button;
    source.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

How would I, in `ButtonClick`, hide the neighbor buttons with the `col` and `row` values?  Is there some sort of getter or setter than I can feed those values into and edit the neighbor's `Visibility` property?

Comment: Are you making some games? If Yes, try some custom panels instead, I could find some samples for you if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int col = Grid.GetColumn((Button)sender);
    int row = Grid.GetRow((Button)sender);
    Button source = e.Source as Button;
    source.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    Grid pGrid = source.Parent as Grid;
    if (pGrid == null) throw new Exception("Can't find parent grid.");

    for (int i = 0; i < pGrid.Children.Count; i++) {
        Button childButton = pGrid.Children[i] as Button;
        if(childButton == null) continue;

        int childCol = Grid.GetColumn(childButton);
        int childRow= Grid.GetRow(childButton);

        if(Math.Abs(childCol - col) < 2 && Math.Abs(childRow - row) < 2) childButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

this iterates through your children and if it is type of `Button` it will check, if the `row` and `column` is next to your `Source` and will hide it.

Comment: When I try to utilize this, the `Grid.Children` segment has red line under it, and the error message reads `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Panel.Children'`.  I'm not super great with WPF, do you know how I get around this

Comment: @user3066571: updated my answer. now it should work. In my example I used a `Grid` with x:Name="Grid" before. Now with using the sources parent it works fine for me.